# URL not updated on NavigationStateChange react-native web-view

Tags: react-native, webview, single-page-application, angular-universal

```
        <WebView
          ref={webView => { this.refWeb = webView; }}
          style={{
            height:height,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
         scrollEnabled={true}
          //Loading URL
          source={
            {
              uri: initialUrl,  
            }
          }
          //Enable Javascript support
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}}
          injectedJavaScript={injectScript} 
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets = {true}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}/>  

     onNavigationStateChange = (navState) => {

          console.log(navState);
            if(navState.url===initialUrl){
                this.setState({
                canGoBack: navState.canGoBack,
                canGoForward: navState.canGoForward,
                changedUrl:false
                })
                }else{
                this.setState({
                canGoBack: navState.canGoBack,
                canGoForward: navState.canGoForward,
                changedUrl : true
        })
       }
     }
```

I am using react-native-webview but onNavigationStatechange not updating navState url it remains same when i click internal links inside webview.

Also got to know some issue due to Single Page Application, Can anyone suggest the approach to handle and overcome this problem.

Comment: Can you show me the code?

Comment: @hongdevelop In above code **navState.url** remains constant yet my page within webview changes

Comment: Did you see what navState contains?

Comment: @hongdevelop my navState contains same url(initialUrl) its not updated

Comment: its now solved by injectedJs
`
let initialUrl = window.location.href;
let checkUrlChange = () => {
const currentUrl = window.location.href;
if(currentUrl !== initialUrl){
window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage('{ \"locationUpdated\": \"' + currentUrl + '\" }');
initialUrl = currentUrl;
}
}
setInterval(checkUrlChange, 2000);`